# Div Selector nth-child

Tags: javascript

[image]

With this function i don't have the quantity with the right code: see attachment. I can't understand why..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var $riepilogo = $('#riepilogo');
        var $btn_riepilogo = $('#btn-riepilogo');
        var parent_table; 
        var quantity; 
        var tot_quantity; 

        $btn_riepilogo.on('click',function(){ 
            tot_quantity=0; 

            $('table',$riepilogo).html('<tr><th>Prodotto</th><th>Quantit‌​&agrave; (tot: <span id="tot-quantity"></span>)</th></tr>'); 
            $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){ 
                quantity = parseInt($(this).val());

                if(quantity > 0) {
                    tot_quantity+=quantity;
                    parent_table = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
                    $('table',$riepilogo).append('<tr><td>'+$('div:nth-child(2)',parent_table).text()+'</td><td>'+quantity+'</td></tr>');
                    $('#tot-quantity').html(tot_quantity);
                }
            });

            $riepilogo.slideDown('fast');

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Add full code please

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $riepilogo = $('#riepilogo');
        var $btn_riepilogo = $('#btn-riepilogo');
        var parent_table;
        var quantity;
        var tot_quantity;
        $btn_riepilogo.on('click',function(){
            tot_quantity=0;
            $('table',$riepilogo).html('<tr><th>Prodotto</th><th>Quantit&agrave;      (tot: <span id="tot-quantity"></span>)</th></tr>');
            $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
                quantity = parseInt($(this).val());

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowledge of the html of the rendered page that you've presented as an image. A wild guess: At the inner node of the tree from which you select the descriptive text (using the selector `$('div:nth-child(2)',parent_table)`), there may be sibling element which are not `div`s that interfere with you counting (ie. the 2nd sibling isn't the div that carries the info you need). The [`:nth-of-type` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)  might better suit your needs.